# What "JavaScript was blocked" in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm constructing a website using WordPress. I've recently begun noticing that, in Chrome, I'm getting a "JavaScript was blocked on this page" error message in my browser bar.

I know that I have JavaScript blocking turned on in Chrome, and I know how to unblock it if I wanted to.

What I don't know is how to find out WHAT Javascript was blocked?  I want to know what my website is trying to do that is being blocked (especially given that everything looks fine despite the fact that some unknown thing is being blocked).

Thanks in advance

Windows 7 & Chrome 58.0.3029.110

============================================================================

Thanks both

1) F12 > Console.  Thanks, I didn't know about this.   No error messages are listed for my website (www.aboutdogs.co.nz) in the console.  Note that I can see error messages for some other websites (including stackoverflow) in the console.

2) I had tried clicking on the error in the URL.  The only error message is "Javascript was blocked on this page", plus radio buttons for "Always allow Javascript" and "Continue blocking Javascript", plus a link to Chrome's Javascript settings.

Comment: Did you press F12 and look at the console messages?  Do that then edit your post to include them if you still need help.

Comment: Did you click on the message in your browser bar?